# Does the telephone pole in the new Twin Peaks appear in the Fire Walk With Me movie?

Tags: twin-peaks

In episode 6 of the Showtime revival of *Twin Peaks*, Richard Horne (presumably related to Benjamine Horne) runs over and kills a little boy with his truck.  Carl Rodd, an old trailer park owner who first appeared in the movie *Twin Peaks: Fire Walk with Me*, witnesses this and then sees a yellow substance leaving the boy's body and going into the sky.  Then we see a telephone pole and hear some kind of weird static in it.

Now in his [New York Times review](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/06/12/arts/television/twin-peaks-recap-part-6-dont-die.html?_r=0) of the episode, Noel Murray suggests that this isn't the first time we've seen this telephone pole:

> Immediately after that gruesome death scene, Lynch cuts to a telephone pole with a number on it (last seen in the film, I believe), with wires emitting still more ominous static and thrum.

My question is, is Murray right that this telephone poll appears in the movie *Twin Peaks: Fire Walk With Me*?  I don't remember it, but then again there are a lot of weird things in Fire Walk with Me, so I may have forgotten it.

Comment: If its same pole then are you trying establish relationship in plot of show and movie. It could be that shooting happened to be at same location in real world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it appears, it's on youtube:

that's from the missing pieces, and this is from the film

Answer (score 0):

It's the same pole with the exact same numbers. It's in the movie when Desmond goes back to the trailer park for the "blue rose"  the pole appears when Carl shows him the deputies trailer which is in clear view of the chalfonts trailer where he finds the ring. The noise we hear from the pole in the Fire Walk With Me is the same noise that the little man "Mikes arm" makes. Your ment to wath the movie with a high volume according to Lynch so you can here the electric pole and the arm make the same noise.